# Relation between tables using C# and EF Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-identity

I'm writing an ASP.NET Core Web API. I separated it into three layers, one for business, one for data access and the API itself.

My models are in the business layer, and I'm using the identity library in the Web API layer to register users and I need to make a relationship between identity user tables and posts, but the posts table is in my layer business.

How can I make this relationship?

I'm trying to make a relation between tables in ASP.NET Core.

Comment: Sounds like a post should have a user identity - the user who created the post.

Comment: Your users became part of business layer and data layer at this point. Usually, you would be having 3 data representations one for each library OR have contract library (which somewhat inconvenient, because each layer can change independently and affect contracts). I know this sound excessive, but you better create API contract (external), Data contract (internal but represents your data layer) and any number of business models, and create mapping between them. This way you are free to do whatever you want and connect them however you like.

Answer (score 0):

Technically all your main models should be in the Data layer, Business layer should have preferably DTO's.

Another think what you can do it, create a separate `Class Library` project for your models.

Answer (score 0):

From your question, You seems to use classic N-tier architecture in the project. In Normally, You need to put the models into data access layer, These models are only for configure database in Dbcontext. Then you need to create DTOs, These Dto Models are for passing data between backend and frontend. You can use `AutoMapper`  to map between Dtos and models.